# Is it possible to transfer money without Internal TXNs?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, tokens, smart-contract-wallets

Exactly what I want is this:

I'm transferring money to a contract. The money coming into this contract will be forwarded to the destination address without creating any TXN (that is, anonymously).

I created a contract and the money sent to this contract is sent to the target wallet. In this way, information does not appear in Transaction transactions of the target wallet.

**the code i use**

```
     receive() external payable {
        payable(0x8162Ac860EF729d60C0f3683bfaA0334A3499956).send(msg.value);

   }
```

**As pictured (see Transactions)**

**
[image]

.

- **So far everything is ok. But there is one problem. Transaction appears in Internal TXNs. I want to hide this.**

[image]

What should happen: Money will be transferred to the contract and it will transfer money anonymously without generating any TX belonging to the target wallet.

**REQUIRE --->>** When the money sent to the contract is sent to the counter wallet, no information will appear in the Transactions and Internal TXNs tab of the counter wallet.

- Is it possible to do this? Please tell me what should I do if
  possible.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Etherscan (and Bscscan) track any transfer and show them in their explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with destroying the contract, you can try this:

```
contract Forwarder {
    receive() external payable {
        selfdestruct(0x8162Ac860EF729d60C0f3683bfaA0334A3499956);
    }
}
```

`selfdestruct` doesn't create an internal transaction, so it shouldn't appear in the explorer.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I am using Solidity 0.8.17. Is it a version-related error or is there a different problem?

Comment: https://bscscan.com/address/0x8177f7C85361c873e3B40250965B11c2Ee477E4C#internaltx

Comment: @hertac Ok, I apologize, apparently bscscan recognizes the self-destruct as a transaction. I don't know about any other possible solutions.